# multiple document ready functions overwriting one another

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have two queries one in the file `test.php` and one in a file `test2.php`... I'd like to refresh the divs every 5 seconds, however the content of div #test gets overwritten by the content of the div test2.
why is this happening? How do i fix it?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#test").load("test.php");
         var refreshme = setInterval(function() {
             $("#test").load('test.php');
         }, 5000);
         $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
    </script>
<div id="test">
    <?php
    include ('test.php');
    ?>
</div>
<br>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#test2").load("random.php");
         var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
             $("#test2").load('random.php');
         }, 5000);
         $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
    </script>
<div id="test2">
    <?php include 'test2.php' ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You're using "random.php" for `#test2`. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: Otherwise, nothing obvious looks wrong with your code and nothing should be overwriting another

Comment: Oh, it's not actually like that! just made that so was more simple

Comment: Your code looks fine. Something else is happening. Can you try your simplified code (I understand you'll have to modify it to work, but it might be worth it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that one of your `.load()` functions will overwrite the other contents is if one of the objects you are loading into is a child of the other.  You should also make sure that you don't have more than one object in your document with a given id because that could cause the jQuery selector to select the wrong object.

You may want to look for any missing close tags in case one is accidentally a child of the other due to a missing tag.

Two `$(document).ready()` calls do not conflict or overwrite one another.  They just queue up multiple functions to be called when the document is ready.

Comment: I over looked through my code a few times, and the only thing i could find that might cause suspicion, is that both test.php and test2.php are exactly the same (class's and id's etc) however they are from different databases. Would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: You cannot have any two DOM elements with the same id in your document at all. If you are loading two pieces of HTML with the same ids, that's a problem.